# Delete parent if the child is deleted

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, one-to-many, cascading-deletes

I want to delete the parent row if the associated rows in child tables have been removed.

```
class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = "children"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("parents.id", ondelete='CASCADE'))

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = "parents"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    child = relationship(Child, backref="parent", passive_deletes=True)
```

If I remove the child

```
child_obj = session.query(Child).first()
session.delete(child_obj)
session.commit()
```

It does delete the child obj but parent remains as it is. I want to remove the parent as well using cascading.

Comment: You may want to have a look to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033547/sqlalchemy-cascade-delete. Also, I have never used passive_deletes attribute, but by reading the documentation, it seems that it does the contrary of what you want.

Comment: @CloC Yes, the post I had seen it before it does the opposite of what I want. I believe there is no straightforward way of doing it using cascading. passive_deletes might not be the best param here but wanted to know what everybody thinks of it. Thanks for the comment though

Comment: I do not believe you can implement purely using sqlalchemy constructs, as this use case is not a very common one.
I would implement it using the SQL level DELETE and UPDATE triggers by checking (and deleting) the rows in the Parent which do not have any more children. If the database allows, one could create a computed column (count of children) and delete all such parents where the children count is 0.

Comment: Also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22471387/99594

Answer (score 2):

You can read this thread:
[Linking Relationships with Backref](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/backref.html)

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    addresses = relationship("Address", backref="user")

class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'address'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

And you can define it in your child class:

```
parent = relationship(Parent, backref=backref("children", cascade="all,delete"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this for simple<sup>*</sup> cases by creating a [listener](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_events.html#persistent-to-deleted) that intercepts deletions of `Child` instances and deletes the parent if there are no other children.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

@sa.event.listens_for(sessionmaker, 'persistent_to_deleted')
def intercept_persistent_to_deleted(session, object_):
    # We are only interested in instances of Child.
    if not isinstance(object_, Child):
        return
    p = object_.parent
    # Handle null parents.
    if p is None:
        return
    cs = session.query(Child).filter(Child.parent == p).count()
    if cs == 0:
        session.delete(p)
```

<sup>*</sup> I would recommend thorough testing if your code is doing things like deleting children and then creating new children with the deleted children's parents in the same session.  The listener works in this case:

```py
c = session.query(Child).first()
p = c.parent
session.delete(c)
c1 = Child(parent=p)
session.add(c1)
session.commit()
```

but hasn't been tested on anything more complicated.

Comment: Note that the `sessinmaker` argument to the decorator is a session factory.  It could be the result of calling `orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)` or whatever your application uses as a session factory.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're referring to is kinda simple. But once the application gets larger, you'd need more sophisticated methods. I, personally, implement a static method `remove` for every class. It takes the `id` and any other parameter necessary to know the delete scheme.

The answer is already given... But that's - not efficient - approach just to give you an example.

```
class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = "children"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("parents.id", ondelete='CASCADE'))
    
    @staticmethod
    def remove(_id_):
        child = Child.query().get(_id_)
        Parent.remove(child.parent_id)
        session.delete(child)

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = "parents"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    child = relationship(Child, backref="parent", passive_deletes=True)

    @staticmethod
    def remove(_id_):
        parent = parent.query().get(_id_)
        session.delete(parent)
```

If you, for example, added a `Column` named `is_old` - in the `Child` class - that's a binary integer 0 or 1 and wanted to delete the `parent` of the `Child` that has `is_old == 1`, It'll be very easy task.