# Flask-SQLAlchemy best approach to taking out parent after removing all children

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, tags, one-to-many

You are able to delete all children after their associate parent gets deleted cascadingly, but what about the opposite way? In this many-to-one relationship:

```
class RecipeTag(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "recipe_tags"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    recipe_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("recipes.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False)
    tag_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("tags.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False)

    parent = db.relationship("Tag", cascade="all, delete", single_parent=True, back_populates="children")

class Tag(db.Model):

    __tablename__  = "tags"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tag = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

    children = db.relationship("RecipeTag", cascade="all, delete, delete-orphan", back_populates="parent")
```

The `RecipeTag` will connect the `Recipe` model with the `Tag` model via foreign keys. However, many recipes will use the same tag, thus a `Tag` can have multiple references from `RecipeTag`. So when a recipe gets deleted, all its associated `recipe_tags` get deleted as well automatically through cascade deletes, leaving some `tags` to be childless. So it doesn't need to exist anymore.

I was thinking of querying all of the tags and pick ones out that have no children left like so:

```
class Tag(db.Model):
    ...
    @staticmethod
    def delete_after_no_children():
        tags = Tag.query.all()
        for tag in tags:
            if not tag.children:
                db.session.delete(tag)
        db.session.commit()
```

This works, but I think it would be wildly inefficient. What would be the best approach to do this?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64401347/2144390

Comment: I guess a listener would be one way to go at it, though I was expecting there would be some sort of query or model statement that I wasn't aware of. The other answers there seem good to try.